# Bootstrap Responsive Navbar (Links Don't Collapse)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to fix a Bootstrap Navbar on my resume. The links work and it's fixed to the top of the resume. When viewing from a smaller screen the Navbar toggle  button appears and the background color toggles open to close and vice versa...But the links aren't toggling with it. I've checked multiple sources but can't figure out what's off.

Any suggestions are appreciated. 
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <title>M.Gillespie Resume</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/helper.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top animated bounceInRight"> <!-- Fixed Nav Bar -->
      <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Top</a> <!-- NavBar Brand -->
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse " id="navbar-collapse1"> <!-- Links to Resume Sections -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active, hover"><a href="#workExperience">Experience</a></li>
          <li class="active, hover"><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
          <li class="active, hover"><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
          <li class="active, hover"><a href="#letsConnect">Connect</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="main">
        <div id="header" class="center-content clearfix, animated bounceInDown">
          <ul id="topContacts" class='flex-box'></ul>
        </div>
        <div style='clear: both;'></div>
        <div id="workExperience" class='gray, animated bounceInDown'>
          <h2>Experience</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="projects" class='gray, animated bounceInDown'>
          <h2>Projects</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="education" class='gray, animated bounceInDown'>
          <h2>Education</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="mapDiv" class=" animated bounceInDown">
          <h2>Where I've Lived and Worked</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="letsConnect" class='dark-gray animated bounceInRight'>
          <h2 class='orange center-text'>Let's Connect</h2>
          <ul id="footerContacts" class="flex-box">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/resumeBuilder.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">

    if(document.getElementsByClassName('flex-item').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('topContacts').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByTagName('h1').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('work-entry').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('workExperience').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('project-entry').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('projects').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('education-entry').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('education').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementsByClassName('flex-item').length === 0) {
      document.getElementById('letsConnect').style.display = 'none';
    }
    if(document.getElementById('map') === null) {
      document.getElementById('mapDiv').style.display = 'none';
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add to `<a href="#IDNAME">` this code: `data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion MaGiO. I tried but no change. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you create a live exemple of code? for example on codepen.io ?